# write clipboard:// not working with red?

Tags: rebol, red

It works with Rebol but not with Red ? Is there a way to make it work ? I tried source clipboard under Rebol to get source code but doesn't work.

Comment: Need `port!`s support for that style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> help clip
   read-clipboard  routine!      []
   write-clipboard routine!      [data [string!]]
```

(As long as full I/O is not implemented) use write-clipboard